# dd performance on Mac OS X vs. Linux

Tags: linux, macos, dd

I was trying to copy an iso of the windows installer onto a hard drive to avoid burning a disk. I first tried Disk Utility's restore function, however it didn't like the ISO for some reason. Then I tried using dd:

```
dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/disk3
```

I realized it was copying the file at a snail's pace, about 160 KB/sec. I rebooted into my linux installation and ran the command again, almost verbatim:

```
dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

This time the command executed in under a minute, with an average speed of 57 MB/sec. In both cases the source and destination were the same physical hard drives. What's going on?

I am running OSX 10.7.3 and Linux 2.6.38-13.

Comment: Hmm, I would expect the linux one to go just as slow without a `bs` parameter.  Do you have an alias for `dd` setup on linux (type `alias` at a prompt)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For OS X, use `/dev/rdisk3`.

For some reason `rdisk` is faster than `disk`. I believe it has to do with buffers.

Also in general using the `bs` flag with `dd` helps with speed.

```
dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

The bytesize is 1M which transfers faster. On OS X you have to use `1m` (lowercase) instead of `1M`.

Comment: Thank you ! I had forgotten to add `bs=1m` and it was slow as hell !

Comment: The comment about the **lowercase m** on OS X was a lifesaver. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

#### BSD raw disks

BSDs in general have 2 disk device types: buffered and unbuffered (raw). From the `hdutil(1)` man page:

```
DEVICE SPECIAL FILES
     Since any /dev entry can be treated as a raw disk image, it is worth
     noting which devices can be accessed when and how.  /dev/rdisk nodes
     are character-special devices, but are "raw" in the BSD sense and
     force block-aligned I/O. They are closer to the physical disk than
     the buffer cache. /dev/disk nodes, on the other hand, are buffered
     block-special devices and are used primarily by the kernel's
     filesystem code.

     It is not possible to read from a /dev/disk node while a filesystem
     is mounted from it, ...
```

Because of the 2nd paragraph, the disk must **unmounted** to be able to use `dd` on it in "raw mode".

#### dd blocksize

From `dd(1)` man page:

```
     Where sizes are specified, a decimal, octal, or hexadecimal number of bytes
     is expected.  If the number ends with a ``b'', ``k'', ``m'', ``g'', or ``w'',
     the number is multiplied by 512, 1024 (1K), 1048576 (1M), 1073741824 (1G) or
     the number of bytes in an integer, respectively.  Two or more numbers may be
     separated by an ``x'' to indicate a product.
```

The default blocksize is 512 bytes...